# Order statistics: probability of second highest order statistics conditional on highest order value

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

I need to calculate a probability of being second highest order statistics for some value, given that this value is a highest order statistics:
$$
Pr(X_{n-1,n}\leq x|X_{n,n}=x)
$$
I guess that the probability is either zero or one, but can not prove it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random set $\{X_{1,n},X_{2,n},\ldots,X_{n-1,n}\}$ is distributed like a sample of size $n-1$ from the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $X\leqslant x$. Thus, for every $y\leqslant x$,
$$
P[X_{n-1,n}\leqslant y\mid X_{n,n}=x]=\left(\frac{P[X\leqslant y]}{P[X\leqslant x]}\right)^{n-1}.
$$

Comment: I am thinking the same way. So if i plug x instead of y then the probability is 1. QED

Answer (score 1):

Is the probability 1 by definition of order statistics?